# Filling areas of Json script with user prompts

Tags: applescript, command-line

I am wanting and Applescript to fill certain parts of a Json script via user input prompts, but not sure how to place the results in the correct areas? And to then have the result copied to the clipboard for pasting.

Json script is as follows:

> /spawn {"notif":" **WordA** ","spawns":[{"name":" **WordB** ","count":
>   **Num1** ,"x":[ **Num2** ],"y":[ **Num3** ],"size": **Num4** ,"hp": **Num5** }]}

WordA, WordB, and Num1 - 5, are the areas I am wanting to fill in via user prompts.

**EDIT:** I have this so far, works for the most part, but not sure how to save the result to the clipboard...? What shows in the dialog result is different from the replies, and result just shows 'OK'.

```
tell application "System Events"
    activate
    display dialog "Write your notification here:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Next"} default button 2
    set WordA to (text returned of result)
    display dialog "Name your beast:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Next"} default button 2
    set WordB to (text returned of result)
    display dialog "Number of beasts to add" default answer "1" buttons {"Cancel", "Next"} default button 2
    set Num1 to (text returned of result)
    display dialog "Location X:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Next"} default button 2
    set Num2 to (text returned of result)
    display dialog "Location Y:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Next"} default button 2
    set Num3 to (text returned of result)
    display dialog "Size your beast:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Next"} default button 2
    set Num4 to (text returned of result)
    display dialog "Set HP for your beast:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Next"} default button 2
    set Num5 to (text returned of result)
    display dialog "      You are set to go, press OK when ready."
    display dialog "/spawn {\"notif\":\" " & WordA & " \",\"spawns\":[{\"name\":\" " & WordB & " \",\"count\": " & Num1 & ",\"x\":[ " & Num2 & " ],\"y\":[ " & Num3 & " ],\"size\": " & Num4 & " ,\"hp\": " & Num5 & " }]}"
end tell
```

Comment: What do you mean a json script?

Comment: If you take out the /spawn the rest is a part of Json. Ive managed to work around the notif error, just not able to save it to clipboard the way it displays in the dialog.